# Docker is taking wrong settings file when creating image

Tags: python, django

I have Django application where my settings are placed in folder named settings. Inside this folder I have **init**.py, base.py, deployment.py and production.py.

My wsgi.py looks like this:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp_settings.settings.production")


application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

RUN mkdir /code
COPY . /code/
WORKDIR /code

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir git+https://github.com/ByteInternet/pip-install-privates.git@master#egg=pip-install-privates

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip_install_privates --token {GITHUB-TOKEN} /code/requirements.txt

RUN playwright install --with-deps chromium
RUN playwright install-deps

RUN touch /code/logs/celery.log
RUN chmod +x /code/logs/celery.log

EXPOSE 80
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    container_name: myapp_django_app
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    command: gunicorn myapp_settings.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:80
    networks:
      - myapp_default
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
```

**Problem**

Every time I create image Docker is taking settings from development.py instead of production.py. I tried to change my setting using this command:

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp_settings.settings.production
```

It works fine when using conda/venv and I am able to switch to production mode however when creating Docker image it does not take into consideration production.py file at all.

**Question**

Is there anything else I should be aware of that causes issues like this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile?

Comment: I added Dockefile and docker-compose since it is multicontainer application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES, there is something else you need to check:

When you run your docker container you can specify environment variables.
If you declare environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp_settings.development` it will **override** what you specified inside of wsgi.py!

```py
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp_settings.settings.production")
```

code above basically means: declare `"myapp_settings.settings.production"` as the default **but** if environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` is declared, take the value of that variable.

## Edit 1

Maybe you can try specifying the environment variable inside your docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp_settings.settings.production
    container_name: myapp_django_app
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    command: gunicorn myapp_settings.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:80
    networks:
      - myapp_default
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
```

Comment: It seems that it is taking development all the time even if I don't change anything or exit VSC, open it again and create an image

Comment: I edited my answer. Did you already check whether you set up your production.py correctly? Maybe the mistake lays in there and the malfunctioning of production.py tricks you into thinking that development.py is running?

Comment: adding environment to docker-compose worked,  thank you

Comment: I am happy it worked out. Anyways I am still wondering why your declaration in wsgi.py did not work. I guess the command in wsgi.py utilizes/runs the `main()` function of manage.py. In case you are also curious: Delete the workaround with setting the environment variables and then state `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp_settings.settings.production")` **either in your manage.py AND wsgi.py**. That's probably it... It just came to my mind